# How can I write in RPostgreSQL's dbListTables() function to get the same results as PostgreSQL's native /dt *name_pattern* command?

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

I have connected to my company's PostgreSQL database using the RPostgarSQL package. I would like to list tables that match certain naming patterns using the dbListTable() function. In native PostgreSQL environment, I can just use psql command

```
\dt *name_pattern*
```

to find tables. How can I do the same thing using RPostgreSQL::dbListTable()?

Comment: Write a function that calls `dbListTable` and then filters the list using a regex and `grepl`.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the information you can get from psql's `\d...` commands comes from the tables in `information_schema`. In your case you can do this:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  table_name LIKE '%foo%'
```